# Подключение синонима домена через SSH подключение

Tags: сервер, ssh

Добрый день у меня возник такой вопрос. Мой сайт не работает через WWW и я хочу добавить синоним к домену через SSH, не знаете как это сделать?

Comment: Отредактировать настройки веб-сервера, который занимается обслуживанием сайта, SSH тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: У вас жуткая каша, но если суть в том что вы хотите что бы сайт начал работать через www или другой поддомен - то вам нужно в настройках доменного имени (в панели регистратора домена или другом месте...) создать нужную запись (www или что там вам требуется) и указать IP вашего сервера.